# Asynchronously set rails authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, csrf, cdn

I have a page that is cached at the CDN level that I would like to have a form submission on.

I have followed [technique 3 of this post](https://www.fastly.com/blog/caching-uncacheable-csrf-security) in order to asynchronously fetch the csrf meta tag and then send those across in the form, but I'm getting `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` in the form submission controller action when I try this. Everything seems to work, but the form is still being denied.

Here is the action providing the csrf info:

```
def csrf_meta
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json do
      render json: {
        param: request_forgery_protection_token,
        token: form_authenticity_token
      }
    end
  end
end
```

And here is the JS function appending it to the `<head>`

```
function asyncCsrf() {
  window.fetch("/async_info/csrf_meta")
  .then(function(response) {
    response.json().then(function(json) {
      console.log(json);
      var meta = document.createElement('meta');
      meta.name = "csrf-param";
      meta.content = json.param;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
      var meta = document.createElement('meta');
      meta.name = "csrf-token";
      meta.content = json.token;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
    });
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Here is the JS adding the authenticity token to the form:

```
var authToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");
// later:
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="'+authToken+'">
```

Everything seems to be there. The token gets passed with the form, but `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` remains nonetheless.

Comment: can you show the code you're using, instead of linking?

Comment: @maxpleaner yeah. Added code. My code is mostly the same as the linked stuff except vanilla js instead of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Well I solved the problem: For some reason the `fetch()` API was returning the wrong session. Good old fashioned `XMLHttpRequest()` works. I think maybe a header is not being automatically included in the `fetch` call but is with `XMLHttpRequest`. I'll investigate independently once I'm past the frustration of this.

Answer (score 0):

`var authToken = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']").getAttribute("content");`

This worked

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.